# Проблемы в работе функции file_exists()

Tags: php, функции, file-exists

В папке с проектом есть каталоги:
data
keys
model
web
В папке model лежит контроллер, который вызывает функцию file_exists(), которая должна выйти из model, зайти в папку keys и проверить существование там текстового файла.

```
$path_to_key_file = "../keys/{$theme}/{$data}/" . $key . ".txt";
if(file_exists($path_to_key_file)) {
// ...
} else $local_err[] = "Ошибка! Файл ".$path_to_key_file." с кеями для ключевика ".$key." Не найден!";
```

Проблема в том, что код выдаёт, что файл не найден, хотя файл там есть, я проверил.

Пробовал разные варианты, в итоге заработал такой вариант:

```
$path_to_key_file = __DIR__."/../keys/{$theme}/{$data}/" . $key . ".txt";
if(file_exists($path_to_key_file)) {
    // ...
} else $local_err[] = "Ошибка! Файл ".$path_to_key_file." с кеями для ключевика ".$key." Не найден!";
```

Вопрос, почему первый вариант не работает? В других частях кода он вроде работает корректно, а тут упорно выдаёт ошибку. В чём может быть проблема? функция file_exists() некорректно раскрывает родительский каталог? Но вроде раньше раскрывала корректно и проблем с ней небыло.

Comment: смотря как вы вызываете контроллер. Если запускается index.php в корне сайта, то путь надо и строить оттуда

Comment: лучше указывать полный путь от корня, чтобы не было путаницы

Comment: проблема может быть в регистре символов, например, в Unix-системах aaa.txt и aaA.txt это 2 разных файла